# Elasticsearch Aggregation Huge Bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an category tree on each document. Like

```
[{
name: "RootCat",
parentId: 104319,
id: 104319
},
{
name: "FirstLevel",
parentId: 104319,
id: 104328
},
{
name: "n Level",
parentId: 104328,
id: 107929
}]
```

The problem when i want to have a tree for each search like :

```
 Root Cat 
   - First Level
      --Second Level-1
      --Second Level-2
```

Aggregations come up with all buckets. And i have about 40000 categories, so it makes huge network traffic. How can i get only categories that i want to show.My filter aggreagtion below

```
.Filter(SearchConstants.Aggregation.Category, 
y =>  y.Aggregations(r => r.Filter("filteredAggs",
cc => cc.Filter(GetPostFilters(searchQuery))                                                  .Aggregations(ra => ra.Nested("cat", 
ty => ty.Path(rtw => rtw.CategoryList).Aggregations(
abc => abc.Terms("categoryId", t => t.Field(q => q.CategoryList.First().Id).Size(0)
```

[image: And here i get all category buckets.All level children]

I want to get one level children with all parents. Like

Root Cat 
    Firts Level 
     Second Level
     (But buckets have all level children)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, by default the search results impact the actual aggregations that are returned. Another option is to use a filter in the aggregation itself. But this is dependent on your requirements. Check the docs for implementing a filter in the aggregation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: I edited my question Jettro. Simply i dont want to get all level children when i get category aggregation.